# Maintain state of a asp Panel control on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page on click event of a button 'X' a panel with some controls get loaded and on the same page I have an another button Y , on clicking second button page is again loading and my panel control is no longer visible,again if I click X its getting loaded if I click Y as page is posted back entire panel is not visible
So kindly help in maintaining state of a panel control on postback.

Comment: What means _loosing Panel control_? Is it not visible at all anymore or is just it's content lost(f.e. a text the user enetered on a `TextBox` which is in the panel)? Do you create the panel and it's content dynamically, is `ViewState` enabled after all?

Comment: You should wrap the second button in an update panel.